# Creating a wizard only JFace application

Tags: java, swt, wizard, jface

I'm working on an application that uses a JFace *Wizard* as its only GUI and I'm a bit unsure as to whether I'm on the right track.

Basically I initiate the GUI like this:

```
Display.getDefault(); // Creates a Dialog (program crashes with a NullPointerException if this is skipped)
Wizard wizard = new SnapWizard();
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(null, wizard); // No Shell needed?
dialog.create();
dialog.open();
```

This seems to get everything running, but is it the "right" way of doing it? Don't I need an SWT *Shell*?

I vaguely remember using a loop for rendering when I used SWT earlier, is this handled automatically by Jface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Shell` will be created if not provided. Event loop is run in `dialog.open();`.

You can check out [JFace Wizard snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/wizard/Snippet047WizardWithLongRunningOperation.java?view=markup).

Comment: That warning is in the Javadoc for `Shell`, but he's creating a `WizardDialog`. And if you go up its hierarchy you'll end up at `TrayDialog` where `null` as parent shell is explicitly allowed: `the parent shell, or null to create a top-level shell`.

Comment: @p12t You're right, I misread the note, which was actually about passing null as parent display (not shell).

Comment: @GustavKarlsson Since there's no way to pass a display into a dialog then there's no other way than to pass null (if you want top level dialog).